# Getting the string-value from foreign key

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I got two classes in my blog-app:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }      
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string PostImg { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }       
    //some other stuff

}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, the post has an int property representing its category. I would like my index-method to be able to take a parameter that can sort the posts by category depending on what is clicked in the view. If category had been a string property directly in my postclass, this would not have been a problem. But now that its only an int, i fail to see how to accomplish this.

Lets say I have a mthod that looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string category)
{            
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Posts = _repository.Posts.Where(o=>o.CategoryId == category).ToList(),

    };   

    return View(model);
}
```

Of course the above does not work cos `categoryId` is an int and `category` is a string. I hope someone can see what im trying to do here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use join statement to get the post which has category with the given name. I assume that category in the parameter is the category name. Otherwise the answer given by Giannis is correct.

```
  public ActionResult Index(string category)
{            
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
       Posts =_repository.Posts.Join(_repository.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryName == category), p => p.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId, (p, c) => p).ToList(),

    };   

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes , category in the parameter is the category name. I will look at this one to! Thank you!

Comment: This works for me so i´ll accept this as an answer. Another question though, if category == null, i would like to get all the posts from the _repository. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a simple if condition for that and write different query if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(category)) {} else {}

Answer (score 1):

You may either declare your argument as int:

```
public ActionResult Index(int category)
{            
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Posts = _repository.Posts.Where(o=>o.CategoryId == category).ToList(),

    };   

    return View(model);
}
```

Or parse it into a variable:

```
public ActionResult Index(string category)
{            
    var categoryId = Int32.Parse(category);
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Posts = _repository.Posts.Where(o=>o.CategoryId == categoryId).ToList(),

    };   

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna try this, i´ll get back to you!